# How could monopods evolve?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, aliens

In Wayne Barlowe's book *Expedition* he has some creatures who have become monopods, or only having one foot. They use it to hop through the dense air. Since the author never really got into the details , how do you see something like this evolving? If you have some other way monopods might evolve, that's allowed too, with one exception. No high gravity sliding on one foot like a snail creatures. That's already been done on deviant art and I want to encourage creativity.

Comment: mollusks have a foot.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollusca#Foot

Comment: This is an excellent candidate for our [Anatomically Correct series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797) and I encourage you to edit your question to meet the requirements of the series.

Comment: This doesn't feel like you're trying to solve a problem or anything similar. Also how do you differentiate good and bad answers? What is your goal?

Comment: I could answer this in a lot of detail. However it would require quite a long essay. In short the factors that have to be taken into account are, Speciation, Sexual Selection, Mutation, Mendelian Genetics, Natural Gene Splicing and Survival. Maybe I'll have a go sometime but don't hold your breath! ;-)

Comment: I concur with JBH: a great candidate for the anatomically correct series! I would ask you to consider theReiley's question though: do you mean monopod in the mollusk sense, or do you mean a bipedal creature that evolved to lose one of its legs?

Comment: How is a mollusc not the right answer?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying. I meant bipedal creatures that evolved to lose one of its legs, like the

Comment: Belly-thrower of Darwin IV. I of course don't think the belly throwing feeding method would work on anything bigger than a starfish, but could its leg work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would a biped evolve into a monoped?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125009/why-would-a-biped-evolve-into-a-monoped)

Answer (score 2):

It is assumed, based on our scientific knowledge, that land animals have evolved from a species of fish which first ventured on the dry land in a distant past. Having evolved from this fish, all animals kept the structure with 4 limbs, deriving from the 4 fins of the fish.

Since you want to develop a monopode, look back at the fishes: do we have any fish which doesn't rely on 4 fins? YES!

The [soleidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleidae)!

[image: Sole]

> Soles begin life as bilaterally symmetric larvae, with an eye on each side of the head, but during development, the left eye moves around onto the right side of the head. Adult soles lie on their left (blind) sides on the sea floor, often covered in mud, which in combination with their dark colours, makes them hard to spot.

Starting from this genus of fishes, organism might evolve leading to a motion like the one of some caterpillars, which use their body like a spring to perform jumps.

[image: caterpillar]

I know, the caterpillars technically have more than one foot, but I am using them as an example to convey the type of movement.

Comment: mollusks, such as snails or even clams, move on their single foot:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xBDwe1FD50

Comment: interestingly, just found this out, cephalopod tentacles are all derived from the foot of their simpler mollusk ancestors.

Comment: If that catepillar is a 'monopod,' wouldn't a snake also be a monopod?

Comment: catepillars are not monopods, they have several hundred or more legs

Comment: How/why would a flounder convergent alien creature, which is supposed to hide on the sea floor, evolve to eventually hop across the land? wouldn't there be other species with more advantage?

Comment: how could a flounder evolved to hop on land? Doesn't the bottom fin flatten and atrophy?

Comment: Sorry, thought the first didn't take

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48_MU9NH2rc This shows a bivalve getting around on land, but how could this evolve further with better alternatives?

Comment: https://www.deviantart.com/antfingers/art/Tripods-682892962 This image gives an interesting idea that a monopod might have first have been a tripod that converted to hopping so the front legs could become tool-using appendages. Not based too much on previous posts. but I want to feel like I'm helping things move along.